# Ignoring a string within a token regex

Tags: java, regex, arcsight

Im trying to parse a log file and having a hard time trying to ignore a string within a token.

Part of the log I'm trying to parse:

```
[Wed Mar 06 20:56:27.121877 2019]
```

I want to create a token for the date where it should ignore any value after the second till the year and look like this:

```
Mar 06 20:56:27 2019
```

My regex string looks something like this at moment:

```
\[\S+ (\S+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)
```

Comment: Can you give complete code how you are using this regex against this entry?

Comment: Hi Aakash unfortunately i cannot share the the log file. However [Wed Mar 06 20:56:27.121877 2019] is at the beginning of the line in each log.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "[Wed Mar 06 20:56:27.121877 2019]";
    String[] arr = test.split(" ");
    System.out.println(arr[1]+" "+arr[2]+" "+arr[3].substring(0,8)+" "+arr[4].substring(0,4));
  }
}
```

Output:

> Mar 06 20:56:27 2019

Comment: theres no where for me to write this code. I need to ignore it in the regex. Thanks in advance

Comment: @GauravBhatnagar : Can you please provide sample code which shows how you want to modify the log file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "[Wed Mar 06 20:56:27.121877 2019]";
    System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]+|\\[|\\]", "").substring(test.indexOf(' ')));
  }
}
```

Output:

> Mar 06 20:56:27 2019

Answer (score 0):

Start the regex from the month, ignore the Day. It would look similar to the below code snippet:

```
String dateform = "[Wed Mar 06 20:56:27.121877 2019]";
    String regex ="(\\S+ \\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dateform);
    if(m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group(0));

    }
```

Output:

> Mar 06 20:56:27